# jQuery - traversing through Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django

I have the following Json object:

```
Object {success: false, errors: "{"email": [{"message": "Enter a valid email address.", "code": "invalid"}]}"}
```

This is response of Django `errors.as_jason` method. I need to process the error message *Enter a valid email address.* I'm using jQuery. I tried many ways but with no success. `json.errors` return this

`{"email": [{"message": "Enter a valid email address.", "code": "invalid"}]}`

but then `json.errors.message` return `undefined` and I didn't find a way to get it correct.

How I can get the message only?

Comment: have you tried with json.errors['email'] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If errors, in your case, is represented by a string, you may need to do the following:

```
JSON.parse(json.errors).email[0].message
```

Well, that's what I'd do, assuming I'm reading your message right.

Comment: This is it. Thanks a lot.